# Filter in Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I wonder if there is any way to filter sites such as "academies" using Google Places? For the idea is to take and use the data from these places.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon.

After researching a lot, I found this tutorial:

These are services calls with Retrofit + Maps.

Thanks ! =)